# Extracting BIND parameters to build a JSON query

Tags: python, regex, json, rest, postman

I have a file which was exported from BIND containing TSIG values for about 500 domain names. I need to repurpose the data into JSON for a REST API query. The BIND data is formatted like so:

```
            //  secondary-example.com.
            key "2000000000000.key." {
                algorithm hmac-md5;
                secret "ahashedvalue=";
            };

            zone "secondary-example.com." {
                type slave;
                file "sec/secondary-example.com.";
                allow-transfer { 1.1.1.1;
                                  1.1.2.2;
                                };
                 also-notify    { 1.1.1.1;
                                  2.2.2.2;
                                };
                 masters {
                   1.2.3.4 key 2000000000000.key.;
                 };
            };
```

From this I need to extract the key, zone and secret. Here's an example API request.

```
            {  
               "properties":{  
                  "name":"secondary-example.com.",
                  "accountName":"example",
                  "type":"SECONDARY"
               },
               "secondaryCreateInfo":{  
                  "primaryNameServers":{  
                     "nameServerIpList":{  
                        "nameServerIp1":{  
                           "ip":"1.2.3.4",
                           "tsigKey":"2000000000000.key.",
                           "tsigKeyValue":"ahashedvalue="
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
```

I'm having difficulty crafting a regular expression appropriate for the scenario. I'm looking construct the JSON in a python script and send the request through Postman.

Comment: You want one regex pattern to extract the key, zone and secret? Or one pattern per variable, like `key ".*?"`, `zone ".*?"`, `secret ".*?"`?

Comment: @Rawing, thanks for replying. I figured this out. I'll post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a couple days reading up on regex and figured out a solution. So, each of those "zones" began with a comment... e.g. "secondary-example.com"... and each set of BIND info was 17 lines long exactly. This solution is hackey and always assumes data is correct, but it managed to work.

1. Separate the zones into chunks of text.

   ```
   zones = []
   cur_zone = ''
   f = open(bind_file).readlines()
   for line in f:
       if line[0:2] == '//':
           zones.append(cur_zone)
           cur_zone = ''
       else:
           cur_zone = cur_zone + line
   zones.pop(0) # Drop the first list item, it's empty
   ```
2. Iterate through those chunks and match the needed parameters.

   ```
   for z in zones:
       z_lines = z.splitlines()
       # Regex patterns to make the required parameters
       key = re.findall('\"(.*)\"', z_lines[0])[0]
       secret = re.findall('\"(.*)\"', z_lines[2])[0]
       name = re.findall('\"(.*)\"', z_lines[5])[0]
       master = re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', z_lines[15])[0]
   ```